# Check if R is running in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I am looking for a way to test if R is being run from RStudio. For some reason I could find the answer on google yesterday but not today, but I think it had to do with testing if a certain system variable was set.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no "running inside RStudio".  RStudio is merely an IDE layer that wraps around R; at the end of the day it just launches the normal R executable you need to have on your $PATH anyway to operate RStudio.

As a proxy, and as R Studio You could test available.packages() for the 'manipulate' package though, or as a shorter version see if RStudio added itself to the `.libPaths()` content:

```
R> any(grepl("RStudio", .libPaths()))
[1] TRUE
R> 
R>
```

*Edit in May 2020 or eight years later*  The question does come up, and one can query a variety of things from within. Here is an example from the terminal of RStudio:

```
$ env | grep -i rstudio | sort
GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE=/usr/share/applications/rstudio.desktop
PATH=[...redacted...]
RMARKDOWN_MATHJAX_PATH=/usr/lib/rstudio/resources/mathjax-27
RS_RPOSTBACK_PATH=/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rpostback
RSTUDIO=1
RSTUDIO_CONSOLE_COLOR=256
RSTUDIO_CONSOLE_WIDTH=111
RSTUDIO_PANDOC=/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/pandoc
RSTUDIO_PROGRAM_MODE=desktop
RSTUDIO_PROJ_NAME=chshli
RSTUDIO_SESSION_ID=9C62D3D4
RSTUDIO_SESSION_PORT=13494
RSTUDIO_TERM=2BD6BB88
RSTUDIO_USER_IDENTITY=edd
RSTUDIO_WINUTILS=bin/winutils
$
```

Similarly, from within the R session:

```
R> se <- Sys.getenv()
R> se[grepl("rstudio",se,ignore.case=TRUE)]
GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE        /usr/share/applications/rstudio.desktop
PATH                             [...also redacted...]
RMARKDOWN_MATHJAX_PATH           /usr/lib/rstudio/resources/mathjax-27
RS_RPOSTBACK_PATH                /usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rpostback
RSTUDIO_PANDOC                   /usr/lib/rstudio/bin/pandoc
R>
```

*Edit in Aug 2021 or nine years later* As all the answers listed here in the different answer may still be too much for people, you can also install package `rstudioapi` from CRAN and then ask it via `rstudioapi::isAvailable()` which comes back `TRUE` for me inside RStudio and `FALSE` in ESS / standard R.

Comment: This works only if the .libPaths has not been changed by a script, which is the case on my company setup

Comment: Well, as they say, "if you break it, you get to keep the pieces".

Comment: another solution (but again, works if you don't load rstudio manually ;)
"package:rstudio" %in% search()

Comment: This one failed for me in RStudio `1.1.442`, with `sessionInfo()` giving `R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23), Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit), Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6`.

Answer (score 63):

This is from `?rstudio`:

```
# Test whether running under RStudio 
isRStudio <- Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO") == "1"
```

There is also `rstudioapi::isAvailable()`, but checking this is not as reliable because RStudio doesn't seem to really need the `rstudioapi` package to work correctly.

Answer (score 22):

Check the `.Platform$GUI` option for `"RStudio"`

```
is.rstudio = function(){
  .Platform$GUI == "RStudio"
}
```

See:

http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/detecting-if-r-is-in-rstudio-and-changing-rstudios-default-graphing-device/

Comment: Unfortunately, this one isn't perfect -- `.Platform$GUI` is not set until _after_ the user `.Rprofile` has been executed (for complicated reasons), and so won't be sufficient for startup scripts. In general, checking the `RSTUDIO` environment variable is preferred.

Comment: @KevinUshey, for those following at home, the suggested approach is then what was mentioned by krlmlr: `Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO") == "1"`? Though, peaking at `rstudioapi::isAvailable`, also mentioned by krlmlr, shows `.Platform$GUI`  being used in the check.

Comment: I think that would be a bug in `rstudioapi` then :) I'll open an issue!

Comment: Note that despite the issue in Kevin's comment, this correctly distinguishes between code run in the RStudio console and run through the Terminal tab in RStudio, unlike the `RSTUDIO` environment variable.

Comment: FWIW, this is the approach employed in the `manipulate` package to distinguish if the IDE is RStudio.

Comment: For completeness, the [implementation of RStudio detection](https://github.com/klmr/box/blob/62cfa4f4a0b836fcadbc7a63de6b9b56857ffb8b/R/paths.r#L185-L195) in the ‘box’ package combines this answer with @KevinUshey’s comment. I’ve found this to be the only robust way.

Answer (score 8):

When I start RStudio it seems to have tools:rstudio in position 2 on the search path. This has a function "RStudio.version" which is undocumented but seems to return the RStudio version string:

```
> RStudio.version()
[1] "0.96.316"
```

So you can define:

```
is.RStudio <- function(){
  if(!exists("RStudio.version"))return(FALSE)
  if(!is.function(RStudio.version))return(FALSE)
  return(TRUE)
}
```

and maybe use that.

Comment: Perhaps this should be `rstudio::versionInfo()$version` now instead of `rstudio::version()`.

Answer (score 7):

As of today, there are a few packages which include functions to check whether RStudio is running:

```
rstudioapi::isAvailable()
assertive::is_rstudio()
```

(list is non-exhaustive)

The `assertive` and `assertive.reflections` packages, resp., do include additional functions to check for other IDEs, desktop/server versions of RStudio, and various `R` releases (e.g., alpha, beta, devel, release, patched, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

To add to the number of nice guesses, here is a message from 2011 (Ice Age)

http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/problems/413-location-of-installed-packages

```
if (Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO_USER_IDENTITY")!= ""){
.libPaths(.Library) # Avoid additional libraries } else { # not rstudio ...
```

Comment: On my setup, Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO_USER_IDENTITY") returns "" whether it is run inside or outside Rstudio

Comment: I checked, it still works ok for me (Windows 7 Desktop). I also checked it on a Virtual Box running Ubuntu and RStudio Server. Please specify your setup so others can check.

Comment: What do you want to know? packageVersion("rstudio") returns '0.97.551', version returns: platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32   arch           x86_64   os             mingw32  system         x86_64, mingw32             version.string R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)

Answer (score 2):

I find the following works for me

```
checkRstudio <- function () {
  return ("tools:rstudio" %in% search())
}
```

I am sort of new to R myself, but I believe Rstudio necessarily loads the
package "tools:rstudio" in order to run.

Comment: So far it seems to be more reliable than other answers, thanks

Comment: Not necessarily.  This can be adjusted in `options` and changed in a `.Rprofile` so as not to be loaded on startup.

Answer (score 2):

Neat solution is now available through the [**`startup`**](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/startup) package via the `is_rstudio_console` function:

```
startup:::is_rstudio_console()
[1] TRUE
```

It may be worth adding that this function checks for two environment variables, `RSTUDIO`, which was mentioned in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17804414/1655567) by [@krlmr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/946850/krlmlr) and `RSTUDIO_TERM` that doesn't seem to be mentioned across the preceding answers at the moment.

```
function ()
{
    (Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO") == "1") && !nzchar(Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO_TERM"))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The most reliable way to detect whether code is running in the main RStudio R session (without relying on the `rstudioapi` package) is:

```r
commandArgs()[[1L]] == "RStudio"
```

Some comments on other answers:

- Checking environment variables may be insufficient, as the `"RSTUDIO"` environment variable will also be inherited by child R processes launched from the main R session.
- RStudio does not initialize its R infrastructure until *after* R profile scripts are run (e.g. `~/.Rprofile`), so checking things like `.Platform$GUI == "RStudio"` or `"tools:rstudio" %in% search()` or `rstudioapi::isAvailable()` won't give what you expect in that context.

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac only the Sys.getenv answer works

platform       x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0
version.string R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)

> Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO")=="1"
>   [1] TRUE
>
> RStudio.version()
>   Error: could not find function "RStudio.version"
>
> any(grepl("RStudio", .libPaths()))
>   [1] FALSE
>
> .libPaths()
>   [1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library"