# Cron job for an R script failing

Tags: r, cron, rstudio

My R script works as intended when I run it on its own, but when I try to run it as a cron job, it keeps failing saying

```
Error: RStudio not running
Execution halted
```

This is the log file for the cron job.

````
Loading required package: methods

Attaching package: ‘lubridate’

The following object is masked from ‘package:base’:

    date

Linkging to ImageMagick 6.8.9.9
Enabled features: cairo, fontconfig, freetype, fftw, lcms, pango, rsvg, x11
Disabled features: ghostscript, webp
Loading required package: bitops

Attaching package: ‘gmailr’

The following object is masked from ‘package:lubridate’:

    date

The following object is masked from ‘package:utils’:

    history

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    body, date, labels, message

Error: RStudio not running
Execution halted```
````

This is my cron job set up

```
## cronR job
## id:   job_3284804a12afb8b01664417646b9fc7f
## tags: 
## desc: I execute things
0-59 * * * * /usr/lib/R/bin/Rscript '/home/rstudio/dev/082017_email/weekly_email.R'  >> '/home/rstudio/dev/082017_email/weekly_email.log' 2>&1
```

```

Comment: When you say 'when it runs on its own', do you run it in RStudio or through the terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to do something that can only be run in RStudio. Maybe one of you functions is trying to call a fucntion that can only be run in RStudio, for example one of the functions from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstudioapi/rstudioapi.pdf)?

In that case, as suggested [here](https://github.com/MangoTheCat/tidyshiny/issues/1), you can make the behavior of your script dependent on whether it's run in Rstudio or not. That can be achieved with the [following line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389158/check-if-r-is-running-in-rstudio):

```
isRStudio <- Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO") == "1"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked! Thanks! The culprit was "rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path"