# Run cron job within RStudio

Tags: r, cron, rstudio

I am trying to schedule a cron job via RStudio on EC2 instance.
When I use a basic script with very basic functions it works fine.
But when I want to schedule a script that contains R functions from specfic R packages, the scripts fails.

My cron looks like this:

```
MAILTO="myemail@adress.com"
36 * * * * /home/user1/Test_for_Cron.R
```

After the script is launched, I receive an email from Cron Daemon specifying something like:

> Error in **R_function** : 
>     could not find function **R_function**
>   Execution halted

From what I found, it seems I have to specify that I want to run the script within RStudio or that I want to "source" it.
I have the feeling the answer might be in the combination of these 3 posts below but I am not finding the solution after testing out some suggestions:

[Check if R is running in RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389158/check-if-r-is-running-in-rstudio)
[Cron job for an R script failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45518592/cron-job-for-an-r-script-failing)
[R command for setting working directory to source file location in Rstudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672720/r-command-for-setting-working-directory-to-source-file-location-in-rstudio)

Help much appreciated !

Comment: maybe try starting the script by printing Sys.info() to check that cron is finding the correct R binary (and library) — ive had smthg like this issue + the problem was cron was finding the wrong version of R

Comment: When I do sys.info() I do not see any information about R libraries

Comment: whoops, try `.libPaths()` and `R.version` -- that'll have the relevant info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misunderstand how `cron` and shell commands work -- an R file is not executable (unless you make a change to it, see below).

*But* if you just prefix it with `Rscript` you can
1. test it in your shell until it works
2. have it executed by `cron` so do

```
36 * * * * Rscript /home/user1/Test_for_Cron.R
```

*Edit:* You can make it executable if you do two things:

- add a `shebang` line `#!/usr/bin/Rscript` (or whatever the path to `Rscript` is)
- change the mode to executable via `chmod 755 Test_for_Cron.R` which sets read/write/execute for you (owner) and read/execute for group and others.